# Use protractor to test loading text

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

In my angularjs application, I need to get some data from remote, and during the time, I showed a "loading data ..." text on the page.

The page is basically like this:

```
<div ng-show="remoteData">
   {{remoteData}}
</div>
<div id="loading" ng-hide="remoteData">
   Loading data, wait ...
</div>
```

And in the angularjs code:

```
function SomeCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/...").success(function(data) {
         $scope.remoteData = data;
    });
}
```

But how can I test it with [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor)?

Since we use mocking files provided in local server in e2e test, the `$http.get(...)` part will run really fast, and when I try to check the "loading" div, it always be hidden since the data has already loaded.

If there any way to test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my application, I decided to implement the following scheme:

- backend, when run in development mode, adds an additional middleware which is looking at the value of the cookie header
- if the cookie header named `__km_delay` is present, it contains a number with the delay set in ms. This middleware will sleep for the given amount of time before handling control to the next middleware

At the same time, I use the following with Protractor:

```
browser.manage().addCookie('__km_delay', millis, '/')
```

And when I'm done with the test, I invoke:

```
browser.manage().deleteCookie('__km_delay')
```

This has the advantage of not having to modify the Angular app logic in any way for testing.

If you're wondering why I chose cookie and not another HTTP header, is because I found no way of setting an extra header with Protractor. And cookie is a header anyway ;)

BTW, I use similar thing to test 5xx server responses.

Comment: I used your solution, but found, with `browser.get(url)`, no matter how long I set the server to wait, it always get final loaded page in protract tests, where the loading text is always hidden when checking. How do you test that?

Comment: Oh yeah, have a look at `browser.ignoreSynchronization`. Also I forgot to mention that setting a cookie wouldn't work in IE9 :/

Comment: I use `browser.driver.get(...)` and it works well. `browser.driver` won't wait angularjs initialization